# How to send form and id with ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I've created an ajax function to input a form in my database, but I also need to bring along the user id so I then can know who that table belongs to. I've tried this with ajax:

```
data: $("#add_form").serialize(), { id : <?php echo $_SESSION['user_id']; ?> },
```

But this does not work, I just get this error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ,` How would I send my id with my form in Ajax? Here is my form:

```
<form action="" method="post" id="add_form" name="add_form">            
<h5>Name: </h5><input type="text" name="name" class="addinput"/>
<h5>Artist: </h5><input type="text" name="artist" class="addinput"/>
<h5>Link to song: </h5><input type="text" name="url" class="addinput"/>
<h5>Lyrics: </h5><textarea name="lyrics" class="addinputtext">Here goes the lyrics...</textarea>
<input type="button" value="Add track" class="loginbtn" /> 
</form>
```

My full ajax call:

```
// this is the id of the form
                        $("#add_form").submit(function() {

                            var url = "includes/addtrack.php"; // the script where you handle the form input.

                            $.ajax({
                                   type: "POST",
                                   url: url,
                                   data: $("#add_form").serialize(), { id : <?php echo $_SESSION['user_id']; ?> }, // serializes the form's elements.
                                   success: function(data)
                                   {
                                       alert(data); // show response from the php script.
                                        $.ajax({ //Get the name of the artist 
                                          url: "includes/getsongs.php",
                                          type: "POST",
                                          data: {id: <?php echo $_SESSION["user_id"]; ?>},
                                          success: function(data) {
                                            //called when successful
                                            console.log("The data is:");
                                            console.log(data);
                                            $(".yoursongs").html(data); //Update
                                          },
                                          error: function(e) {
                                            //called when there is an error
                                            console.log(e.message);
                                          }
                                        });
                                   }
                                 });

                            return false; // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.
                        });
```

PHP code

```
    <?php 

include 'db_connect.php';

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO song VALUES (?)");
$stmt->bind_param('ssssi', $name, $artist, $url, $lyrics, $userid);   // bind $sample to the parameter

// escape the POST data for added protection
$name = isset($_POST['name'])
          ? $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['name'])
          : '';
$artist = isset($_POST['artist'])
          ? $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['artist'])
          : '';
$url = isset($_POST['url'])
          ? $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['url'])
          : '';
$lyrics = isset($_POST['lyrics'])
          ? $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['lyrics'])
          : '';
$userid = isset($_POST['userid'])
          ? $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['userid'])
          : '';

/* execute prepared statement */
$stmt->execute();

printf("%d Row inserted.\n", $stmt->affected_rows);
echo 'done';

/* close statement and connection */
$stmt->close();


?>
```

Comment: provide full ajax call

Comment: dont just show data:    Please provide full Code

Comment: the way I usually do it is by adding a hidden input to the form, that way your session variable will be included when the form is serialized

Comment: Given that the $_SESSION['user_id'] is a server variable. Why not access it directly in your PHP script where you do the saving of the form?That way you are not exposing yourself to attacks whereby a third party can change the user id in the javascript..

Comment: @Mysteryos And how would I do that from my PHP script? Updated post with code.

Comment: On this line:
$stmt->bind_param('ssssi', $name, $artist, $url, $lyrics, $userid); 
Replace $userid with $_SESSION['user_id'];
Which becomes:
$stmt->bind_param('ssssi', $name, $artist, $url, $lyrics, $_SESSION['user_id']);

Comment: @Mysteryos And that would be really fun to know, because I have multiple ajax calls depending on the user id.

Comment: Same method as above. 
Simply replace your user_id variable in your PHP scripts with the $_SESSION['user_id'].

Comment: @Mysteryos But when I do that it doesn't work... It's just blank in the log. Even if I've included the functions.php file :/

Comment: Make sure that where you are using the $_SESSION php variable, the following line 'session_start();' is included at the top of the script.

Comment: @Mysteryos Wow, how did I miss that? :P Well, thanks! :D

Comment: Glad it worked for you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently your `data` is not correctly set, since `serialize()` will turn the form values into a querystring, hence you can use `&` to concatenate your `id` value into this string:

```
data : $('#add_form').serialize() + "&id=" + <?php echo $_SESSION['user_id']; ?>,
```

instead of:

```
data: $("#add_form").serialize(), { id : <?php echo $_SESSION['user_id']; ?> },
```

Comment: if I have multiple parameters?Like Id and also Name?

Comment: Then just continue concatenate your string like: `"&id=" + <?php echo $_SESSION['user_id']; ?> + "&name=" + <?php echo $_SESSION['user_name']; ?>`

Answer (score 0):

You may use following code to post values via ajax

```
var queryString = $('#formId').serialize();

queryString     += '&id='+ <?php echo $_SESSION['user_id']; ?>;

$.post('post-url', queryString, function(data) { 
   //validation code 
},"json");
```